# How to use Transparent Data Encryption in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, transparent-data-encryption

I'm struggling when trying to implement DTE in my local Oracle 19c environment (with pluggable database ("orclpdb")).
What I'm trying to do:

1. Create sys user (done)
2. Create "admin" user (done):

```
alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
alter session set container=orclpdb;

create user admin identified by admin;
GRANT connect, resource, SYSKM to admin;
```

3. Create encryption wallet (done)

```
select wrl_parameter from v$encryption_wallet;
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT CREATE KEYSTORE 'MY-WALLET' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD;
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE OPEN IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD;
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET ENCRYPTION KEY IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD WITH BACKUP USING PASSWORD_2;
```

4. (Here is the problem). Now as an "admin" user (see picture below with the connection details), I want to create a table with an encrypted column.
   [image]

When opening the wallet:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET ENCRYPTION WALLET OPEN IDENTIFIED BY oracle;
```

I get the following error:

```
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

I don't find anything useful on the internet how to grant access for "admin" user to accessing the wallet. Can you please help?

Comment: Off-topic for this site, but.... [you may need to connect `as syskm`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-D222FF09-2984-4233-8291-FA13FC6D71D6) - not sure if that's an option in the 'Role' drop-down or is only has `sysdba`?

Comment: Tried this too, but still same error

Comment: @AlexPoole Why off-topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide and managed to do it: https://oracle-base.com//articles/12c/multitenant-transparent-data-encryption-tde-12cr1